# method chaining failed in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to train myself to write chaining function but got error of

`Cannot read property 'minus' of undefined(…)`

What's wrong with my code?

```js
var math = function(){
   var result = 0;
   
   var add = function(param){
     result += param;
   };
   
   var minus = function(param){
     result -= param;
   };
   
   var print = function(){
      console.log(result)
   };
   
   return {add:add, minus: minus, print:print};
}

var calculator = math();
var result = calculator.add(5).minus(1).print();
console.log(result)
```

Comment: Your functions don't return anything explicitly. So calling `calculator.add(5)` will return you `undefined` which, of course, does not have a `.minus`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to return the object (`this`) in this case, to "chain" like you are expecting

You `print()` also doesn't return anything so `result` is always undefined.

```js
var math = function(){
   var result = 0;
   
   var add = function(param){
     result += param;
     return this;
   };
   
   var minus = function(param){
     result -= param;
     return this;
   };
   
   var print = function(){
      console.log('result: ' + result);
      // print doesnt return anything, it needs to if you want to assign anything by calling it
      return result;
   };
   
   return {add:add, minus: minus, print:print};
}

var calculator = math();
var result = calculator.add(5).minus(1).print();
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also store a reference to the object returned.

```js
var math = function() {
  var result = 0;

  var add = function(param) {
    result += param;
    
    return math;
  };

  var minus = function(param) {
    result -= param;
    
    return math;
  };

  var print = function() {
    console.log(result)
  };
  
  var math = {
    add: add,
    minus: minus,
    print: print
  };
  
  return math;
}

var calculator = math();
calculator.add(5).minus(1).print();
```

Comment: why not just use `this`?

Comment: *shrug*  I'm more used to using 'this' when there is a new involved.  This snipplet didn't use new.